# Check for values return from EnumValue

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

I'm reading values from registry using EnumValue. I want to check the  existence of all values from the registry and pop up error message if any value is empty.

```
key = OpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, r'Software\myapp\path', 0,KEY_READ)
for i in range(0,6):
    n,v,t = EnumValue(key,i)
    value = str(v).split(',')
if (value[0:] == ''):
    dlg = wx.MessageDialog(None,'value is empty','Alert',wx.OK|wx.ICON_ERROR)
    dlg.ShowModal()
```

value returns

```
['1000']
['10MS/s']
['Edge']
['500']
['']
['Rise']
```

How can i have all the values return from EnumValue in a single list so that i can iterate this list and find if any value is empty?
Tried ','.join([value]) but didn't work!

Comment: `if not all(value):`

Answer (score 0):

I found answer myself

```
import wx
from _winreg import *
empty = False   
key = OpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, r'Software\myapp\path', 0,KEY_READ)
for i in range(0,6):
    n,v,t = EnumValue(key,i)
    value = str(v)
    if value == "":
        empty = True
        break
if empty:
    dlg = wx.MessageDialog(None,'value is empty','Alert',wx.OK|wx.ICON_ERROR)
    dlg.ShowModal()
```